# mod_rewrite making a directory available from all directories/subdirectorries

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to link a directory like:

```
/resources/IMG/
```

to all other directories like

```
/IMG/ would resolve to /resources/IMG/
```

and also

```
/foo/IMG/bar/anything.img should resolve to /resources/IMG/bar/anything.img
```

with .htaccess. I have tested several methods of doing this, which one would be the best working one?

EDIT: SOLUTION

```
# Add trailing slash to any directory if not done so
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]


# MAP /resources/IMG/ to be avaible as /IMG/ from everywhere
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/IMG/
RewriteRule ^(?:.*/IMG/)(.*)$ /resources/IMG/$1 [L]
```

The best way of dealing with /IMG (without trailing slash) is to firs map it and then add the slash, but since it is a 301 redirect it will refresh the REQUESTED_URI and the url will be /resources/IMG/ but if you always add a trailing slash it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
DirectorySlash Off

# Add trailing slash to any directory if not done so
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/IMG [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:.*?/)?(IMG(?:/.*)?)$ /resources/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Tested it, doesnt seem to work at all. I tryed it with /web/IMG/ but I get a not found(404)

Comment: Make sure this is your first rule in your .htaccess. You can place your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed my current code a little, I appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: Insert my suggested rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: I tested the current code and I put it right after the rewriteengine on, but sadly it causes a redirect-loop, any idea what went wrong?

Comment: ok check update, make sure it is just below RewriteEngine On line.

Comment: I don't think it can work without the /resources/IMG/ folder being mentioned in the code, look at the question again, the IMG folder is in /resources/IMG/ while the web folder is in /web/

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you changed the question, it was different earlier.

Comment: That pretty much did the trick except I removed the R flag, since that was what I'we been looking for, but sadly it's not yet perfect, it allows /abcIMG/ which i fixed by forcing a trailing slash before IMG: RewriteRule ^.*(/)?(IMG/.*)$ /resources/$1 [L] but one more thing, it needs to accept both /IMG/ and /IMG but the current code requires it to have a trailing slash.

Comment: Works like a charm except it handles /IMG (without trailing slash) with the R flag and makes the rewritten url visible in the url bar, the one with trailing slash resolves fine though, thanks for the help so far

Comment: No I don't have any `R` flag in my rule

Comment: /IMG looks like  /resources/IMG/ (with redirect) in URL bar while /IMG/ looks like /IMG/ which is the way it should be

Comment: Sorry, but tested it and /IMG is still /resource/IMG/ while /IMG/ still looks alright

Comment: Tested again, I always test it in new browser and clear cache, nothing carries over, sadly still the same issue.

Comment: If `/IMG` is a real directory then `/` is added by `mod_dir` automatically. But what problem you have with `/resources/IMG/`?

Comment: Both /IMG and /IMG/ resolve to /resources/IMG/ but /IMG/ looks like /IMG/ in the URL bar after it is resolved, while /IMG looks like /resources/IMG/ instead of /IMG/ after it is resolved

Comment: That way the trailing slash is not being added at all, so /IMG looks like /IMG is there any way to add the slash to it?